# How to execute multiple commands in Stackexchang.Redis CLI in windows?

Tags: redis

I am trying to execute multiple commands one after the other in redis cli through batch file, redis pipelining but could not find the working solution.

Here is my command:

```
127.0.0.1:6379>$(Auth Test12\r\nPING\r\n;)

error : Invalid Arguments

$ (printf "PING\r\nPING\r\nPING\r\n"; sleep 1)

Error : Invalid Arguments
```

Using Cmd.exe in ProcessStartInfo in c#

```
FileName:Cmd.exe
Arguments: @"/c cd c:\program fies\redis && call redis-cli -a Test12 config set requirepass Test1234.
```

Tried same command in .bat file also.

```
Error: redis-cli is not recognized as internal or external batch command
```

My Requirement is to authenticate with existing password and Set new password to redis server from C# code.

If anyone could suggest on this, it would be a great help.

Comment: You should show your batch. Honestly it is not a problem with a redis server. You're just not sending the right commands to redis-cli.

Comment: when double clicked on .bat fil its running perfectly but when running with ProcessStartInfo in c# its giving error : redis-cli is not recognized as as an internal or external batch command

Comment: in .bat file i have written below commands: cd c:\program files\redis                               call redis-cli -a Test12                                                                                                       config set requirepass Test1234

Comment: Basically you just make to make sure you can call `redis-cli` from within your batch file. 1. try use quote around the path c:\program files\redis and 2. actually try if you can run redis-cli in c:\program files\redis 
At this stage it is a very basic DOS batch file problem.